# How to construct a linear mapping base on the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $v=(1,1)$ and $w=(2,1)$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. How to construct a linear mapping $T:\ \Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $v\in$ Ker$(T)$ and $w\in$ Im$(T)$. (Find the matrix of such mapping with respect to the standard basis).

In my opinion, to let $v\in$ Ker$(T)$, that means $T(v)=(0,0)$? This way $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix} $ would work. But how about $w\in$ Im$(T)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to proceed, but the important thing to remember is that a linear map is uniquely determined by where it sends any basis. Choosing the standard basis $(e_1,e_2)$ here, we have $v = e_1 + e_2$. We want to have $w \in \operatorname{im} T$, so we may *define* $T(e_1) := w$ to ensure this. Now all that is left to determine $T$ is to define $T(e_2)$. But in order to have $v \in \ker T$ we need to have $$0 = T(v) = T(e_1) + T(e_2),$$
so we should put $T(e_2):= -T(e_1) = -w$.

Thus the matrix of our $T$ with respect to the standard basis is $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & -2 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$